# Python range for multiple iteration

Tags: python

I was told that if you'd like to iterate over the list multiple times, it's probably better to use range. This is because xrange has to generate an integer object every time you access an index, whereas range is a static list and the integers are already "there" to use.

So,i deduce that the list created by the range method remains in memory enough to be re-iterated. When will that list be destroyed ?

Comment: When nothing references it anymore. As a side note, it's better to use Python 3.

Comment: I am curious :)

Comment: do you have a highly specfic usecase where you **need** an answer to this ?
else it is best not to touch memory management of python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, `range(n)` returns a list of numbers from `0` up to `n-1`.

If you code

```
for i in range(1000000):
```

then your program creates a list of a million integers, and throws it away when the `for` statement ends. That list has to be constructed in memory, and that can be expensive, if your code does it often.

If you code

```
for i in xrange(1000000):
```

then your program doesn't create a list of a million integers: instead you get a sort of iterator. But it will still be destroyed at the end of the `for` statement. The `xrange()` function dates from Python 1, before the language had iterators as first-class constructs, but the idea is much the same. It is not a data structure but a chunk of code that returns the next number when you ask for it, instead of generating them all beforehand.

So your deduction "that the list created by the `range` method remains in memory enough to be re-iterated" is incorrect. (Though I think you meant `xrange` not `range`. Either way, it's wrong.)

If you want a `range()`-generated list to persist in memory, do this:

```
 myrange = range(1000000):
```

Then you can do

```
for i in myrange:
```

as many times as you like and you will pay the overhead of creating a list of a million integers only once.

If your range is of the order of dozens or hundreds, not millions, and you need to ask this question, then you should not be fretting about efficiency.